# Dynamically imported module in react won't react to Mobx observable

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I load a react component dynamically (via webpack's import('module').then) into my bundle. The problem is that the component won't react to Mobx observable's changes. If i import the module the normal way everything works.

Looking at Mobx dev tools i can see that when the component is statically imported when the observable changes i see:

Updated ‘ReviewsStore@6.profile’: (ReviewsStore@6.profile) (was (ReviewsStore@6.profile))
Scheduled async reaction ‘Reviews#0.render()’
Reaction ‘$Reviews#0.render()’

In contrary when i use code splitting i don't see any render invoked:

Updated ‘ReviewsStore@6.profile’: (ReviewsStore@6.profile) (was (ReviewsStore@6.profile))

Bellow is my code with test data

```
class ReviewsStore { // My store
@observable profile = {};

@action
getProfile() {
    $.ajax({ url })
        .then(action((data) => {
            this.profile = {
                user: 'John Doe',
                userid: 123,
                followers: 25,
                reviewsCount: 22,
                reviews: [
                    {
                        body: 'Lorem ipsum ',
                        date: '20/12/2016',
                        rating: 4.5,
                    },
                    {
                        body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit',
                        date: '23/12/2016',
                        rating: 4.2,
                    },
                ],
            };

        }));
}
```

}

```
@observer class Reviews extends Component { // My View
constructor() {
    super();
    this.getProfile = this.getProfile.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        asyncModule: null,
    };
}

getProfile(id) {
    this.props.store.getProfile(id)
    import('../components/reviews/user-profile')
                .then(({ default: Profile }) => {
                    this.setState({
                        asyncModule: <Profile user={this.props.store.profile} />,
                    });
                });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.state.asyncModule}
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify mobx package is included only once? Only in your base bundle and not again in your splitted of bundles?

Comment: My splitted component is only 4kb and i'm not importing mobx anywhere in that file, btw my component is a stateless component, i don't know if it matters i'm just trying to give you clues that would help. (i've tried turning it into a class component and adding observer decorator but i don't see any change).

Comment: Update: I made the most basic app just to check if the problem remains and it is. I'd be grateful if you could take a look when you find time! you can find it [here](https://gitlab.com/Sgus/mobx-code-splitting-demo)   (Btw great talk at react Amsterdam!)

Comment: Could you file an issue in the mobx repository? There are probably people in there that have actually experience with code splitting :)